# Spring - detect dependencies not annotated with @Component

Tags: java, spring

With Guice, getting an instance of A will automatically resolve B even if I have not defined anything about B.

```
public class A {
  @Inject B b;
}

public class B {
  ... 
}
```

However, Spring seems to require that components are marked with @Component or another stereotype.

I have some common libraries that need to work with different CDI implementations. How can I get Spring to automatically construct instances without annotating with @Component or defining every single class in my @Configuration?

Comment: You can't, without changing much of the underlying infrastructure, ie. custom `BeanFactory` or `ApplicationContext` implementations.

Comment: in Guice ,this happens because @Inject B is a concrete class. but real DI usage is not like this, that means even in Guice also we need to bind them.

Comment: @hunter I understand that in Guice you need to specify the concrete implementations for interfaces, but not everything has multiple implementations, so I'm only talking about concrete class injection here

Comment: @bcoughlan Different methodology. Spring is different from Guice, and is not intended to work the same way, so don't expect it to. Spring is explicitly designed to only *resolve* dependencies, not to *create* beans from dependencies. Just because `A` depends on `B`, doesn't mean that a `B` object should be injected. It could be that you want a *subclass* of `B` injected. *You* have to tell Spring what you want.

Comment: @bcoughlan , i agree but it is not basically about multiple implementations.lot of DI usages has single implementations, but it is used to separate the api module and impl module clearly, so some other module can inject a interface we defined in our api, but actually instance from impl will be injected. in this case also it is a single implementation.